# Netlogo: is it possible to import timestamp and turtle from the same CSV?

Tags: csv, datetime, netlogo

I'm new to netlogo. I have been able to load and print a CSV file but now that I want to generate the turtles from CSV I have trouble finding a good solution.

My csv file is structured
[as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6u2k.png)

I have ran into some online examples treating the generate turtles with agents from rows, but my # of observations are too large to pivot. I would like to generate a turtle set based on each column which changes into the next value after a tick. Or is this not possible and should I make another csv with initial turtle list without datetime and value shifts? Advise is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of a screenshot and external link, please give us a snippet of your CSV file, formatted as a code block, here.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that is definitely possible and not too complicated to do. You can start by using the number of columns to create as many turtles as you need, then using tick counts and turtle identifiers to choose and update the data you are reading from your csv. The following code should work as long as your time intervals are regular.

```
extension [csv time]
globals [my-csv current-time]

turtles-own [value]

to setup
  set my-csv csv:from-file "my-csv.csv"
  set current-time time:anchor-to-ticks (time:create "2011/01/01 00:00") 15 "minutes"
  create ((length item 0 my-csv) - 1) turtles
end

to go
 tick
 update-turtle-values
end

to update-turtle-values
  ask turtles [
    set value (item who (item ticks my-csv))
  ]   
end
```